# Modify android first installation time

Tags: java, android, root, xposed

There's:
`packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0).firstInstallTime;`

How can we modify it? Maybe with root/xposed or programmatically

Comment: What are you exactly want to modify?

Comment: I want to modify apk first install time

Comment: Why do you need to modify APK? It's need root permission

Comment: Yep, as i say in question, root and xposed - is no problem

Answer (score 0):

Xposed Framework is the perfect tool for this!

Xposed Framework can "Hook" any function call to execute any code of your choice before/after that function - or completely replace that function (Note - it can only hook functions, not fields).

Hence in your case, you want to hook `packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0)` and change the `firstInstallTime` field in the object that the above function is returning.

However, `packageManager` is an abstract class, `getPackageInfo()` is an abstract function - and xposed cannot hook abstract functions. What you need to do is hook the class the class actually implements that function.

That class is `ApplicationPackageManager` - simply hook its `getPackageInfo` function, and whenever this function is called, you can modify the field `firstInstallTime` in the returned object to your liking. You can use `afterHookedMethod()` function of xposed to do this.

ApplicationPackageManager: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/ApplicationPackageManager.java#ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29

afterHookedMethod: http://api.xposed.info/reference/de/robv/android/xposed/XC_MethodHook.html#afterHookedMethod(de.robv.android.xposed.XC_MethodHook.MethodHookParam)